# Python not appending to list

Tags: python, matching, file-writing

I have a script that I've used before that uses a list of keywords to query a master file with multiple columns and entries. The script should read the masterfile line by line and when it encounters a keyword it writes the whole line into a new file.

The keyword file looks like this:

`A2M,ABCC9,ACADVL,ACTC1,ACTN2,ADA2,AGL`

The master file looks like this:

```
8:27379821,8,27379821,[A/T],NM_001979,NM_001256482,NM_001256483,NM_001256484,A2M,A2M,A2M,A2M,,Silent,Silent,Silent,Silent
GSA-rs72475893,8,27380763,[A/G],NM_001979,NM_001256482,NM_001256483,NM_001256484,AM,AM,AM,AM,EXON,Missense_R1407W,Missense_R1307W,Missense_R1257W,Missense_R1407W
8:27381207,8,27381207,[A/C],NM_001979,NM_001256482,NM_001256483,NM_001256484,ADA2,ADA2,ADA2,ADA2,,Silent,Silent,Silent,Silent 
GSA-rs117056676,6,72385948,[T/C],,,,,AADACL2-AS1,AADAC,EXON,Silent,Silent,Missense_X400Q
```

The desired output would then be:

```
8:27379821,8,27379821,[A/T],NM_001979,NM_001256482,NM_001256483,NM_001256484,A2M,A2M,A2M,A2M,,Silent,Silent,Silent,Silent
8:27381207,8,27381207,[A/C],NM_001979,NM_001256482,NM_001256483,NM_001256484,ADA2,ADA2,ADA2,ADA2,,Silent,Silent,Silent,Silent
```

The code I'm using is below. The problem I'm having is that the "matches" list variable seems empty, it is not appending anything. Why could this be? Is it not making any matches? or is it because it's not appending them to the list?

I've tried using the masterfile and keyword file as .csv and as .txt but none work.

Thank you for any help!

```
#open the list of words to search for
list_file = open(r'file.csv','r')

search_words = []

#loop through the words in the search list
for word in list_file:

    #save each word in an array and strip whitespace
    search_words.append(word.strip())

list_file.close()

#this is where the matching lines will be stored
matches = []

#open the master file
master_file = open(r'file2.csv','r')

#loop through each line in the master file
for line in master_file:

    #split the current line into array, this allows for us to use the "in" operator to search for exact strings
    current_line = line.split()

    #loop through each search word
    for search_word in search_words:

        #check if the search word is in the current line
        if search_word in current_line:

            #if found then save the line as we found it in the file
            matches.append(line)

            #once found then stop searching the current line
            break

master_file.close()

#create the new file
new_file = open(r'file3.txt', 'w')

#loop through all of the matched lines
for line in matches:

    #write the current matched line to the new file
    new_file.write(line)

new_file.close()
```

Comment: `.split()` separates the string on whitespace (which doesn't seem to exist in your file) by default, *not* commas.

Comment: Simple debugging would reveal that `current_line` probably doesn't contain what you think it does. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @jasonharper thanks! that seemed to fix it.

Comment: @Woodford line was actually working fine, iterating until the end. Still a very useful resource for future, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried adding two print statements to see what's going on behind the scenes and found that the first file you were reading you weren't splitting the sentences into separate words.

search_words was stored like this:

```
search_words = ['hello this is a line']
```

instead of like this

```
search_words = ['hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'line']
```

I have modified line 10

to this: `search_words += (word.strip()).split()`
instead of this: `search_words.append(word.strip())`

Here is the modified code:

```
#open the list of words to search for
list_file = open(r'file.csv','r')

search_words = []

#loop through the words in the search list
for word in list_file:

    #save each word in an array and strip whitespace
    search_words += (word.strip()).split()

list_file.close()

#print (search_words)    

#this is where the matching lines will be stored
matches = []

#open the master file
master_file = open(r'file2.csv','r')

#loop through each line in the master file
for line in master_file:

    #split the current line into array, this allows for us to use the "in" operator to search for exact strings
    current_line = line.split()

    #print (current_line)

    #loop through each search word
    for search_word in search_words:

        #check if the search word is in the current line
        if search_word in current_line:

            #if found then save the line as we found it in the file
            matches.append(line)

            #once found then stop searching the current line
            break

master_file.close()

#create the new file
new_file = open(r'file3.txt', 'w')

#loop through all of the matched lines
for line in matches:

    #write the current matched line to the new file
    new_file.write(line)

new_file.close()
```

Comment: It's better practice to use `.strip()` after you have split the terms, otherwise you will only remove spaces from at the ends of the string before it's split, not from each term.

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize there was no separator between them as visually they were apart from each other. Thanks!

Comment: @Da Chucky An empty split() function removes any number of spaces between a string :D

Comment: @Da Chucky posted a solution as well, you can look at it and also see whether I might have overlooked something.

Comment: @SeekNDstroy Yes that's true, but that assumes that you are splitting on spaces and not some other token such as `,` (which you need to do in this case).

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues at a glance:

Iterating on the file will give you the lines, not split on the `,` character. You need to use `.split()` before using `.strip()` and appending to your search list. I've removed the iteration through each line since your example input only has one line, but you can add it back in easily enough if you wish to have multiple lines.

Second, `.split()` will by default split on   (a space), not `,`, so you need to specify that as an argument to `.split()`.

With those fixes (and using context for opening files), the fixed code is:

```py
search_words = []
with open(r'file.csv','r') as list_file:
    for word in list_file.read().split(","):  # Fix 1
        search_words.append(word.strip())

matches = []

with open(r'file2.csv','r') as master_file:
    for line in master_file:
        # Not strictly necessary, we can search in the string using in
        current_line = line.split(",")   # Fix 2

        for search_word in search_words:
            if search_word in current_line:
                matches.append(line)
                break

with open(r'file3.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    for line in matches:
        new_file.write(line)
        print(line)
```

Result:

```
8:27379821,8,27379821,[A/T],NM_001979,NM_001256482,NM_001256483,NM_001256484,A2M,A2M,A2M,A2M,,Silent,Silent,Silent,Silent
8:27381207,8,27381207,[A/C],NM_001979,NM_001256482,NM_001256483,NM_001256484,ADA2,ADA2,ADA2,ADA2,,Silent,Silent,Silent,Silent
```

(Note that the console output has extra new lines between each line)